# How to link blade.php file jquery scripts in app.blade.php in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

I need to link the following blade file jquery script with app.blade.php file.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('[name=name]').keyup(function(){
            if($(this).val()){
                $('div.somename').show();
            }else{
                $('div.somename').hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

how can I link above jquery scripts with app.blade.php file?

Answer (score 1):

Lets say the above jquery code resides in `custom.js` in `public/js` folder, than you can attach this file in blade file like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/custom.js') }}"></script>
```

The function `URL::asset()` produces the necessary url for you.

Note: Put the `jquery.min.js` in blade

Comment: Put the `jquery.min.js` in blade and try again

Comment: now working. can you give me link this with app.blade.php as @extent